# Viewing MSIL as expression tree

Tags: c#, expression-trees, cil

I'm currently building a compiler for my language into MSIL, and use Reflector to inspect the IL.

Is there a way to visualise the IL as an Expression Tree that could be used to generate the IL instead?

Comment: There used to be a Reflection.Emit language plugin for reflector. Not quite expression trees. Perhaps CCI can help.

Comment: CCI Looks interesting, I'll take a look of that when I get back home!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [FxCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for this, with a [custom rule](http://www.binarycoder.net/fxcop/html/index.html) that writes to a text file or something.

---

Note: FxCop works on compiled managed code (DLLS/exes), not sure about starting from IL. I suggested this answer as you say you're using Reflector to get IL, implying you're starting from compiled managed code.